# How to create non-image cross browser circle

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How to create cross browser, JS or CSS, simple circle and beeing able to change its radius and color.

I dont exclude .png solution, but it must be costumizable (size in `pixels`, color in `hex`).

IE7,8 must be, IE6 optional.

Comment: You do realize pngs are images, right?

Comment: yup. It should not be image-based, but If it would be and can be still costumizable, its ok.

Comment: You can achieve this with Canvas, but it's probably not compatible with IE. [Canvas Tutorial, draw a circle](http://billmill.org/static/canvastutorial/ball.html)

Comment: How about o works in all browsers

Comment: I've tried css behaviour property, but it didnt work.

Comment: Oh wait, I saw a personal coding army somewhere around here... not.

Answer (score 4):

How about using a library like [Raphael](http://raphaeljs.com/) to make the circle. It's cross-browser and very light @ 89Kb. It uses SVG for compliant browsers, and VML for IE.

> Raphaël currently supports Firefox 3.0+, Safari 3.0+, Chrome 5.0+, Opera 9.5+ and Internet Explorer 6.0+.

Here's [a simple circle example](http://jsfiddle.net/DA3GP/) as found on the homepage:

```
// Creates canvas 320 × 200 at 10, 50
var paper = Raphael(10, 50, 320, 200);

// Creates circle at x = 50, y = 40, with radius 10
var circle = paper.circle(50, 40, 10);
// Sets the fill attribute of the circle to red (#f00)
circle.attr("fill", "#f00");

// Sets the stroke attribute of the circle to white
circle.attr("stroke", "#fff");
```

Comment: @user1576183 yes, it's in the DOM.

Answer (score 2):

[With SVG](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/shapes.html#CircleElement):

```
<svg width="200" height="200" viewBox="0 0 200 200"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
    <desc>Example circle01 - circle filled with red and stroked with blue</desc>

    <!-- Show outline of canvas using 'rect' element -->
    <rect x="1" y="1" width="198" height="198"
        fill="none" stroke="blue" stroke-width="2"/>

    <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="50"
        fill="red" stroke="blue" stroke-width="10"  />
</svg>
```

Or using HTML5's `canvas`:

```
<canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
```

```
//get the canvas' context.
var c = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext("2d");

// Draw canvas outline
c.fillStyle="blue";
c.fillRect(0,0,200,200);
c.fillStyle="#fff";
c.fillRect(2,2,200- 4,200- 4);

//draw the circle
c.fillStyle="#f00";
c.beginPath();
c.arc(100, 100, 50, 0, Math.PI*2, true); 
c.closePath();
c.fill();

c.lineWidth = 10;
c.strokeStyle = '#00f';
c.stroke();
```

Please note, however, that both these techniques aren't supported on IE 8 or lower.

**[Working Sample](http://fiddle.jshell.net/edqss/2/)**

Comment: The question states that IE 7 support is required. IE does not support SVG before version 9.

Comment: Canvas is also IE 9+.
I honestly doubt there is a option out there for IE 8-

Comment: The best thing would be to call a page which generates the canvas then saves it as base64. The base64 is then sent as AJAX to the server which could probably (in some way) read it and store it in a .png file which could then be called in the page shown to the user?

Comment: @Ghillied: Yea, php can do that. I prefer Raphaël, like suggested in another answer, as that eliminates the need for a extra server call.

Comment: Of course, I didn't know about Raphael which seems like the best answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here's oldie, but goodie. Fully cross-browser compatinle, no SVG, Canvas etc. required:

http://codecorner.galanter.net/2008/01/16/dhtml-javascript-graphics-draw-without-flash/

Answer (score -1):

You can also create any shape using font-face:
This font has a circle: http://www.fontriver.com/font/fnt_basic_shapes_1/
If you want it to have a border, you can overlay one on top of another.

http://caniuse.com/fontface